# Add attribute in sub mode of yaml file content by using sed command

Tags: bash, sed, yaml

Here is my content of yaml file

```
web:
   image: apache
   volumes:
      - "./app:/src/app"
   ports:
      # - add ports here
```

I need to add one attribute as `type` under `web` using `sed` command.

Expected output:

```
web:
   image: apache
   volumes:
      - "./app:/src/app"
   ports:
      # - add ports here
   type: none
```

How we can achieve this by making use od `sed` command.
I tried often using `sed -r 's/^web (type\s*:\s*\s*$)/\1type: none/' file_name` this command,  but it needs `type` already to be exists in data. But I have to add new attribute to data under `web`

Comment: `sed` is not a particularly well-chosen tool for the job; particularly for a syntax as complex as YAML's, any code trying to perform edits with `sed` will only work properly with a very limited subset of the language's available syntax. I'd strongly suggest storing the content in JSON (JSON is a subset of YAML) and using `jq` for edits, or calling out to a language with YAML libraries (such as Python or Ruby) for the job.

Comment: i tried `jq` but it will change the format then..@CharlesDuffy

Comment: Yes, it will -- but it'll still be syntactically identical. Might I suggest two different copies of your file, one structured for human generation (and modified *only* by humans), and one in machine-readable form?

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a clean solution, but if the comment

```sh
# - add ports here
```

stays like that, you can just add it after that line:

```sh
sed -i '/# - add ports here/a \ \ \ type: none' your_file
```

This will add the right amount of spaces as well.

Comment: ports value could be any, how we can take hardcoded @NullDev